# Is it acceptable to use the same CSRF Token for a whole session?

Tags: security, token, csrf, owasp

Is it acceptable to use the same CSRF Token for a whole session? I don't see any reason to change the CSRF token with sessions that extend no more than a couple hours.

Is there any reason to use single use tokens? In my experience these often cause a bad user experience.

Comment: I guess generating random token is preferred because XSS+CSRF attack can not be protect the user with a single token throughout the session.

Comment: What exactly is the bad user experience with single use tokens?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading [OWASP's CSRF cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

It is a valid option to use a single token for the entire session, but beware that your site may contain vulnerabilities that can circumvent your CSRF defenses. Such as XSS or simply a lack of encryption when sending/receiving the sensitive pages.

I personally use session tokens, but added a bit more. I divided the possible user actions into tiers, where the highest tier contains the most sensitive actions and the lowest tier are the common non-sensitive actions. For the highest tiers I require users to authenticate once more, while the middle tiers only need the session CRSF token.

Hope this helps :)